# How do I find my SSH public key on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, ssh, rsa

I am trying to find my SSH key on [Windows Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server) through PowerShell or CMD.

I don't have the option to install [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY). Basically I need all the details on my SSH key, but I am having no luck whatsoever.

The Linux machines were easier, as we had PuTTY installed.

Comment: Does it have an SSH Key? I don't think they have one by default, you need to generate one before you can use it, for which it's easiest to install and use puttyGen (though there are alternatives). Also, this question definitely belongs on SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Please specify how you generated the ssh key. By default, OpenSSH stores it at `~/.ssh`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can find your *id_rsa.pub* file which contains your key. Did you use OpenSSH to generate the key?

The default location for saving the public key is `C:\Documents and Settings\username\.ssh\` or `C:\Users\username\.ssh`

Default file names can be:

`d_dsa.pub id_ecdsa.pub id_ed25519.pub id_rsa.pub`

Or you can just type this in your Git Bash:

`ls -al ~/.ssh`

This will list all the files in your *.ssh* directory.